# ReSharper conventions for names of event handlers

Tags: c#, resharper

When I add new event handler for any event, VS creates method like `object_Click`. 
But ReSharper underlines this method as Warning, because all methods should not have any delimeters such as "_".

How can I customize rules of ReSharper so that it doesn't underline such methods? Or may be I should rename such methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I got it at work but at the moment I dont recall, will follow up with rule if I remember.

Comment: I was wrong, I just lived with the warning for events it seems. =/ sorry

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Personally, I'd suggest renaming the methods. Generally I think VS comes up with terrible names for both controls and events.

I prefer to make a method name say what it *does*, not what calls it. That promotes reuse as well. Admittedly the signature of an event handler is often not ideal for reuse - I'd argue that often a lambda expression calling a method with more sensible parameters would be useful:

```
button.Click += (sender, args) => SaveCurrentDocument();
```

but obviously the designer doesn't support that :(

Of course, renaming all the methods is going to be more work than just changing the R# settings, if you can find some that work...

Comment: But the method in question IS doing what it says. It's handling the fact that a button was clicked. If the desired action is to save the document, then the button click handler should call some other method to do that. I dislike a lot of code in the event handlers for just this reason. It also gets in the way of wiring up multiple actions to the same result (button click, menu item, context menu item, etc). If each of these handlers call the same common method, then there's no confusion.

Comment: @Mel: But then why bother having the method? Wouldn't the lambda expression as per my example be clearer?

Comment: In most cases, I think it would. For an event such as clicking on a row within a grid, then I think the event handler should be responsible for interpreting the control-specific information such as determining which row was clicked, and perhaps extracting the bound object before passing it off to a well-named method that does something with that object. If this can be done within a lambda, then great. Sometimes it's nice to have it broken out in a "proper" event handler for clarity, though. As always... it depends.

Comment: I think this approach makes sense, but what about an event handler that you want to attach _and_ detach? In that case the lambda expression would not work, because it cannot be detached reliably. In that case you _do_ need a method, but both `object_Click` and `OnObjectClick` (or `OnClick`) seem wrong to me. The latter because it is exactly the same name is what would be used for the protected event raising method in the declaring type.

Comment: @Riko: You could come up with a wrapper method in that case, which just called the "normal" method. Ugly, but it would work. Possibly "SaveCurrentDocumentAsHandler"?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, that's effectively what I decided to do. I've also decided to shelve my dislike of the `OnTargetEventName` pattern and use that, as it makes clear what's going on. Not sure if I'll change my mind at some point. Probably ;-)

Comment: @Jon: It would be great if Visual Studio could sort out its auto-generated event handlers at some point. Leads a lot of people down the wrong path, plus 2010 **still** uses full event handler assignments without delegate inference, and there's no way to change it.

Comment: BTW: `Pro WPF in C# 2010` recommends to keep the event handler methods and the actual logic behind them separate. *"This 
pattern gives you the flexibility to change where your [logic] code is located, replace the [control] with a different control, and wire several controls to the same process, all without limiting your ability to change the user interface later."*

Comment: @Kos: For WPF if you're using MVVM you'd hopefully put the logic in the ViewModel to start with...

Comment: Agreed ofc, but this approach sounds reasonable regardless of the API.

Answer (score 112):

For C# (or VB), make the following change:

ReSharper | Options | Languages | C# | C# Naming Style, Advanced settings...
Change 'Event subscriptions on fields' from `$object$_On$event$` to `$object$_$event$`.

You may also want to add additional rules to entity kinds like 'Types and namespaces' to account for code-generated classes such as '*Default'.  For example, add a new rule with a '*' Name Prefix and a Name Style 'UpperCamelCase'.

Comment: In my case it was changing $object$_On$event$ to $object$_$event$ (removing the 'On'). Otherwise, method names like Page_Load were still underlined.

Comment: Is there a way to modify it so the  $object$ starts with an uppercase letter?

Answer (score 6):

I just created an extension for Visual Studio 2010, EventHandler Naming, that lets you specify with a simple pattern what you want your generated eventhandler names to be. The default pattern in the extension is On$(SiteName)$(EventName) which will give you event names like OnBtnNameClick instead of btnName_Click. You can get the extension at http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2010/12/22/better-eventhandler-names-in-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 0):

On your file menu you should have "Resharper" Click it -> Options -> Naming conventions (on left menu).

From there you can specify what naming conventions are used for each of the naming types/styles.

Comment: Thanks, but ReSharper allows to add some rules like UpperCamelCase, lowerCamelCase, ALL_UPPER, all_lower, First_upper. But I need something like this - UpperCamelCase_UpperCamelCase.

ReSharper 5 have "Advanced settings" but I can't write right rule.

Comment: @PavelBelousov Resharper 7 can handle the restrictions you mention here. I have mine set up to allow the following for private methods: lowerCamelCase_UnderscoreTolerant, _lowerCamelCase_UnderscoreTolerant, UpperCamelCase.  I'm pretty sure R# 6 also could, since that's what I was using at my last job.