# Naming Event Handlers: How to make the first letter uppercase

Tags: visual-studio, naming-conventions, resharper

I usually name the controls of my window application starting with a lowercase letter. Eg:

`startButton`
`optionsListBox`

And when I suscribe (through *VS*) to an *event* of one of those controls, it automatically gives names like:

`startButton_Click`
`optionsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged`

but *ReSharper* suggests renaming it to:

`StartButtonClick`
`OptionsListBoxSelectedIndexChanged`

Reading [ReSharper conventions for names of event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994774/resharper-conventions-for-names-of-event-handlers)  I saw I can modify through *ReSharper* how *event handlers* will be named. *Eg:*

From `$object$_On$event$` to `$object$On$event$`. That will remove the `_` character, but what about the first letter?

**Is there a way to tell *VS* or *ReSharper* to make *event handler* names uppercase by default?**

Comment: With ReSharper, you currently can't do that. Please file a feature request to youtrack.jetbrains.net if you'd like to see this improvement in future ReSharper versions. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "EventHandler Naming" extension for Visual Studio 2010 allows you to configure precisely how to generate event handlers from the visual studio designer. 
For instance you could configure it with "On$(SiteName)$(EventName)" and then specify that the SiteName should be PascalCased.

The extension can be [downloaded here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/14f62cb9-b559-4bad-9388-37da2150e238/?SRC=Home)