# how to turn of certain VS warnings?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to turn off some Visual Studio warnings including:

- Field can be made readonly
- Name doesn't match rule...
- Use implicitly typed local variable declaration

But probably some of the goes from some plugin like `Resharper`? I'm not sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those all sound like Resharper suggestions...

You should be able to change the "inspection options" right at the point of the warning.  If you change it from Warning to Hint (or disable it entirely), it will not prompt you anymore.

Answer (score 0):

- Disable "Use implicitly typed local variable declaration"

  1. ReSharper->Options
  2. Code Inspection->Inspection Severity
  3. Scroll down to "**use 'var' keyword when possible**" and change to "Do not show"
- Disable "Field can be made read only"

  1. As above, but with "**Field can be made read only**"
- Name doesn't match rule...

  1. I think this is the answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345137/28411