# Rename ClassName_SomeEvent() handlers to SomeEventHandler()?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, event-handling, naming-conventions

**Edit 2:** Actually `SomeEventHandler` is more concise than `OnSomeEventHandler`:

If I let Visual Studio generate an event handler for me, the name is ***like this***:

```
private void ControlOrFormName_SomeEvent(object sender, SomeEventArgs e) { }
```

For example, the `Load` event handler of a form becomes:

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

I don't find this scheme attractive, it has an underline, etc. Besides, it's private, so I thought of this:

```
private void LoadHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

I expect this won't confuse anyone (it's an open source project I'm starting) and since it resides in the control, I see no other possible meaning for `MyForm.LoadHandler()`.

Does this make sense? Am I missing something that warrants the name having the class name?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because you're looking for opinion and your own question is an opinion itself. Follow official conventions or skip them, but no answer to your question will give you a definitive argument to go your way or other.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer But the accepted question did give me a definitive argument: it can't be `OnEvent` because it's already used. Past from that, it's a matter of convention (and I agree that it wouldn't make sense to change this in a project that's already in progress with several places to refactor). Besides, my point is that the class name has no use, and there is a definitive argument that can be raised against that: give me a scenario where that class name would add value to the handler name.

Comment: Sadly I believe you didn't understand the official convention: it's not about "class name". Ok, when you handle a click in some Form, the event handler will be called "FormClassName_Click", but you forgot that **a Form is a control too**. The convention isn't "className_eventName", it's "event source identifier_eventName". You're right, class name is useless, because it's not the class name!!!!!!! It's the control ID.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer But even if it was a control it would be the class name, and I don't see where it would be different (it's just an auto-generated name by the designer, in other places where people use event handlers I don't even see this "convention" at all). And now that I have noted it, there's no written convention about this behaviour, so it's more like leaving control names as `Button1` and Form2` instead of an actual coding guideline.

Comment: Are you confusing a control identifier and a class name? It's not the same "btnSave" than "Button". First is a control identifier, later, class name.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer You are right. I spent too much time away from C# and forgot how it did certain things. I've also never liked Hungarian-like control prefixes, so they always ended up as "saveButton" (yes I know this is also controversial). I may go back in my decision, maybe I'm just too damn stubborn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already an `OnLoad` method in the base `Form` class, as well as many other `OnEvent` methods that are protected. You generally `override` these methods in your child classes when required.

In your form's code type `protected override On` and `IntelliSense` would show you that this naming convention is already used so if you defined the same methods you would hide the inherited members.

**Update**

It's up to you but the important thing is **being consistent** with whatever naming convention you choose throughout the project and making sure everyone in the dev team is aware of the naming convention. Personally, I wouldn't bother as it would cause unnecessary headache later on when the project grows.

> The power of naming conventions doesn’t come from the specific
>   convention chosen but from the fact that a convention exists, adding
>   structure to the code and giving you fewer things to worry about. -Steve McConnell

Comment: +1 for updating the answer. But please explain what headache it would cause. It feels innocuous and actually a readability improvement to remove the class name (as in `Class.Class_Event`).

Comment: I'll accept this since I don't think anyone will post anything beyond "be consistent" and "people are used to the default". It might take a couple of seconds to see that `SomeEventHandler` is a *handler* for *SomeEvent*, but I guess every project has its conventions. Being consistent ***and*** concise are things I aim for.

Comment: @CamiloMartin, I agree that your version is more readable; the unnecessary headache is getting the other devs on board with your version, thus making _your version the convention_. And if you don't do this, you'd then have to deal with code that follows no particular convention which would be a nightmare. Then again, if you're the only person working on your project it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: I understand people have to be aware of the guidelines; hence I'll have a short "getting started" document with this and just a few other conventions (one of them being that all code must pass FxCop "All Rules" without warnings, and I'm adding StyleCop to the mix currently).

Answer (score 1):

Generally `On<EventName>` is used to ***raise*** the event and nothing else.

Comment: Oh I see. So I wouldn't be able to rename it?

Comment: You can rename it but don't prefix with `On` it will only confuse you and other developers. It's a convention, you can not respect it but it's highly recommended...

Comment: @CamiloMartin You edit doesn't change the point that you can follow well-known naming conventions or just use your own ones. It's up to you ;)

Comment: As said, you can use the naming you want, just be clear with yourself. Code should be easily understood by others people too ;-)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes, Hungarian Notation is a well known naming convention too.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I know that, but Microsoft .NET conventions are these: love or hate it. Hungarian notation is widely-used in .NET, but event handlers have this convention. Do you like it? Good! Do you dislike it? Nice, but ANYTHING different to OFFICIAL conventions will make your code less common to a large number of Microsoft .NET and C# developers. Is this a good point for you if you're going to develop an open source project? Do you want collaboration or you'll make it yourself alone? :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Honestly, I don't want to attract developers who would use Hungarian prefixes just because it's popular. In the same sense, I also rename `Form1` to `MeaningfulNameForm`. In any case, I plan to put all handlers on a `Handlers` Region in the hope this helps.

Comment: @CamiloMartin It's up to you, you know: conventions are absolutely arbitrary, you could like it or not ;)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio assists you on following well-known .NET naming conventions.

You can follow them or just use your own ones.

After all you know why widely-used naming conventions are the right way of doing things: a good number of developers should understand your code with less effort.

Comment: Question edited. I still don't like that default convention, [not even Jon Skeet does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2994962/124119). I'm all for conventions when they make sense. An underscore?

Comment: @CamiloMartin With all respects to Jon Skeet. I don't care about these kind of opinions. A naming conventions is arbitrary: you'd like it or not, but a convention enforces collaboration and optimizes any development. Official convention is what you don't like: follow it and others will understand your code in seconds, or follow yours and make others cry with your ones.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but I make a case that short names are better than longer names and that `OnLoadHandler` is clearly a handler for the `OnLoad`. It's not like I'm naming it something obscure or complicated (and I'll be consistent).

Comment: Are you sure? We're in 21st century hey! Do we need to abbreviate everything because method identifiers eat computers' memory? Or makes sense drop these underscores because compiled program will use a lot of hard disk space...? In .NET "OnXXXX" refers to "raise an event" in any assembly of .NET and third-parties follow this convention. For me, "[control identifier]_[event identifier]" is an event handler, and "OnXXX" is an event raiser. For me and for most .NET developers. And what's consistent or not, is just an opinion. For me, the official convention isn't terrible: it's fine.

Comment: I'm not concerned with the disk space usage, I'm concerned with `OnLoadHandler` being more readable than `HeyLookImAFormThatHasAName_Load`. Heck, it still could even be just `LoadHandler`. I just don't see where the class name is useful.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Let me know how much readable is your convention because I won't never know **who** is the event source?

Comment: IMO generated event handlers are fine because the only code I write into them is the code to a call of a function. It has multiple pros : 1) You know all controls that are bound to this event. 2) The function you call is meaningfull and there is no logic in event handlers.

Comment: You will know because you'll see the method in its class (as in `MyButton.ClickHandler`), and that's why you have an IDE. Also, if you refer such a method to someone else verbally, normally you'd say "the button's click handler" anyway.

Comment: @ArnaudF. I also only write code to call other methods in event handlers. But it's quite redundant to have `MyClassName` all over the place when it's even in the filename/tab label/etc (I have a file for each class).

Comment: As I said in the other question, it's up to you. Usually, in this case, a verbose identifier saves time. And I'm agreed: luckly, we've a powerful IDE. But as I said in another comment too, I don't find any reasonable point to drop "[event source]_[event identifier]" convention, it's just your opinion (and others one, why not), but since opinions are just subjective points, that's why conventions are there: less debate, more efficiency.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I'd have to disagree that Hungarian notation has made anyone more efficient. And then you have `void prfx_HorriblAbrvi8edName (LPCTSTR lpszStr)`. I spend half the time coding and half cursing (but I understand certain horribly verbose conventions make sense in less-than-ideal environments)

Comment: @CamiloMartin It's not Hungarian notation what makes people efficient: I'm talking about conventions. These makes people efficient. Your own convention makes you more efficient because you work in an environment you like and you feel it's the best way of working yourself. But if you want to open source your code, I believe you'll need to deal with conventions even if you don't like them!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes, but all projects I've seen have some coding style to them anyway (and maybe even a coding guidelines document). Even when I'm answering with a code snippet here, I usually write it in the form the OP writes (casing, bracket alignment, etc). So if it has to have its own style anyway, I'd rather use a guideline which values readability.

Comment: By the way just wanted to add the [Philips Healthcare coding guidelines for C#](http://www.tiobe.com/content/paperinfo/gemrcsharpcs.pdf) use this: `private static void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs args) { }` (which is how I originally thought, but now I'm going for a variation of that - note that they also customized `EventArgs e` to `EventArgs args`, something that Petzold claimed to prefer in his [.NET book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/) (which is what I've read to get started with C#).

Comment: @CamiloMartin Book writers are developers and persons, and they've opinions like you. Which isn't subjective is the official guidelines. Again: you can like or dislike them, but creators of the platform gave these conventions haha