# Can you change the default for the auto-generated parameter names in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, customization

I am using VS2010 and Resharper 7.1.3
Whenever I double-click a button to generate the default event handler I always have to go back and change it because it does not comply with my Resharper naming rules.

Is there a way for me to set the default parameter names so that rather than getting

```
button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I can get:

```
button1_Click(object argSender, EventArgs argEvtArg)
```

It's a pain renaming them all the time.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, as this goes against 99.9% of all C# style guides. And anyways, this comes from the event handler.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3345137/225780

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: why not name the arguments what I want? And argument name of 'e' does me no good. And just because the IDE put it there doesn't mean it's the best idea.

Comment: @Adrian; that's not what I'm talking about at all. That's how to get Resharper to stop complaining about method names. NOT how to get VS to stop making useless parameter names.

Comment: @TomPadilla No it doesn't, but if it's what the **official Microsoft style guidelines** recommend it sure as hell is.

Comment: Sorry, but 'because MS says so' is the worst argument I can think of. Do you still use button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click) rather than the delegate inference button1.Click += button1_Click()? Blech. I know how to code, I don't need MS telling me what my variable names are.