# Bad naming of the VS created functions: button_click

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

According to the `Framework Design Guidelines` by Microsoft, the good naming convention for methods is `PascalCasing` and underscore is not a good option. But why default method naming for events is used underscores.
For example the default name for a button's click event is `buttonCancel_Click` instead of something like `ButtonCancelClick`.

If it is an exception to methods (which seems OK) how is possible to add this exception to Visual Studio so the warnings disappears?

I'm using resharper, so there is another problem which is how do add this exception to resharper rules.

Comment: I can at least comment on the casing that the name of the button is used, so your buttons name should already be upper cased. Also I cannot give you a link but if you follow MS guidelines they also state that you should use readable logical names so that's why in a lot of newer examples you see `CancelButton` instead of `ButtonCancel`.

Comment: @Silvermind I'm agree with your opinion that using underscore in this situation makes code more readable. So how to get rid of those warnings that visual studio shows?

Comment: @Silvermind: "your buttons name should already be upper cased" - and this will violate the next guideline - field names must be in camelCase. :D

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3345137/399576 for instructions on how to edit R# method inspection rules

Comment: @Dennis you're right, but I meant it for the delegate. If you want that upper cased automatically you should give your control a Pascal name. I should have been clearer about that obviously :) I prefer using upper case for conrtrol names to make it a little more clear in the code behind that it must be a control since I we almost never use public fields and it is not declared in the code behind class. But to each his own.

Comment: So I conclude that suggesting a name like a buttonSave_click is just a SUGGESTION and it's recommended to change the method name in a way the name describes what it does, not where it's been called for example: `SaveCurrentForm` instead of `buttonSave_click`