# Resharper convention for "event subscription on fields" to start with uppercase?

Tags: c#, resharper, naming-conventions

This question is based on the original message that you find here:
[ReSharper conventions for names of event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994774/resharper-conventions-for-names-of-event-handlers)

I have the same question like the commenter on the second answer: Is it possible to let the Event subscription by default start with an uppercase letter? So if the button is called "btnOK", generate a method called "Btn"?

And before you asked, I'm aware of Jon Skeets answer, but still am curious if this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not aware of a build in way, but there was a VS Plugin see http://einaregilsson.com/better-eventhandler-names-in-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 0):

For any event added in code/xaml (e.g. added with ReSharper's Create Method) the Naming Style settings of ReSharper will apply (see ReSharper->Options->Code Editing->C#->Naming Style).

As for anything named by the Designer View you have to stick to renaming. You could speed up things a little by using Refactoring Rename (Ctrl+R+R). Once the dialog is open press down array and use the first suggestion (which is also according to the set Naming Style).

You could of course always make a feature request at JetBrains but I think it is quite likely what you want is not possible because otherwise I think they would already have added such a feature. Still asking wont do any harm.